# is 退屈は石になる an expression or it's wrongly translated?

Tags: translation

Taikutsu wa ishi ni naru , "boredom becomes a stone". is this an expression or it's wrongly translated? What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: Does "boredom becomes a stone" make sense? What does it mean?

Comment: @YuuichiTam are you just quotting me or are you really asking? It doesnt make any sense to me. does it mean you are really bored or something? are stones supposed to be boring? Like when you are bored and you start throwing stones?

Comment: The literal translation of "boredom becomes a stone" is "退屈は石になる" but I think it doesn't make sense. I think "boredom" don't generally relate with a stone, though throwing stones can imply their boredom. As the answer said, it is odd that feeling become a object except the world of fantasy or poem, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I visited the site:
https://www.letras.com/kiyoshi-hikawa/limit-break-x-survivor/
and I found the following lyrics;
  (Woo-hoo) taikutsu wa
  (Woo-hoo) ishi ni naru
  Omokute ochichau mae ni (let's fly high)

Now I got the meaning of the "taikutsu wa ishi ni naru". In this lyrics, the expression "The boredom becomes a stone." may be allowed, though having some unnatural tone as a Japanese language.
   I paraphrased the lyrics of this song as follows;
   We are flying in the sky. We feel bored very much. Our boredom is heavy like a stone. Yes, "the boredom becomes a stone." It is becoming heavier and heavier so as not to be able to fly. If we keep bearing the boredom, we are threatened to fall onto the ground by the heaviness. Let's shake off the boring feeling, and let's fly up high in the sky before falling onto the ground.

I thought that the lyrics are full of hope and give it to the person who sings the song of them.

Answer (score 2):

## 日本語

1. 結論{けつろん}として、"Taikutsu wa ishi ni naru" 「退屈{たいくつ}は石{いし}になる」は、日本語として不完全{ふかんぜん}とまでは言{い}いませんが、不自然{ふしぜん}だと感じました。従{したが}って、「退屈は石になる」の英訳｛えいやく｝文"boredom becomes a stone"を吟味｛ぎんみ｝して、この英訳文作成者{えいやくぶんさくせいしゃ}である質問者｛しつもんしゃ｝が日本語の原文｛げんぶん｝の意味｛いみ｝を正｛ただ｝しく理解｛りかい｝しているかどうかを判断｛はんだん｝することはあまり重要｛じゅうよう｝でないと思います。
2. この表現{ひょうげん}をインターネットで探{さが}すとhttp://anond.hatelabo.jp/20170213160617で見つかりました。日本語の文章{ぶんしょう}として初{はじ}めて表現{ひょうげん}された文章かも知れません。
   インターネットの例{れい}は
   　（woo-hoo）退屈は～
   　（woo-hoo）石になる～
   　重くてー落ちちゃうー前に～
   　 と３行{ぎょう}の詩{し}のようになっており、行の配置{はいち}全体{ぜんたい}を通{つう}じて倦怠感{けんたいかん}（フランス語のアンニュイennui）を表{あらわ}そうとしていると思われます。
3. インターネットの例ではなく、「退屈は石になる」の文章を考えてみます。「ＡはＢになる」は、文法的{ぶんぽうてき}に日本語として正{ただ}しいと思います。例えば「蛹{さなぎ}は蝶{ちょう}になる」は、「蛹は羽化{うか}して蝶になる」という意味の文章の中｛なか｝の「羽化して｛うかして｝」という部分｛ぶぶん｝を省略{しょうりゃく}したものと言{い}えます。この例では、ＡもＢも実態{じったい}のある物{もの}（生物{せいぶつ}も含{ふく}む）です。しかし「退屈は石になる」の例では、Ｂ（＝石）は物ですが、Ａ（＝退屈）は物ではありません。Ａ、Ｂのいずれも物の場合{ばあい}は、「ＡはＢになる」は日本語として自然{しぜん}ですが、Ａ、Ｂのいずれか一方{いっぽう}が物でない場合は不自然です。しかし、作家{さっか}など、文章の表現{ひょうげん}に優{すぐ}れた人が、例{たと}えば自分{じぶん}の感情{かんじょう}を的確{てきかく}に表{あらわ}したくて比喩法{ひゆうほう}を使{つか}った場合には、やや不自然な日本語ですが、Ａ、Ｂのいずれか一方が物でない場合でも存在{そんざい}し得{う}る文章かも知れません。
4. 最初{さいしょ}にこの文章を見たとき私は、偉大{いだい}な作家である夏目漱石{なつめそうせき}が自分のやるせない倦怠感｛けんたいかん｝を表して、「退屈{たいくつ}嵩{こう}じて石になる」とつぶやいた情景{じょうけい}を思{おも}い浮{う}かべました。なお、「退屈嵩じて石になる」は、私が「退屈は石になる」を基{もと}に書{か}き直{なお}した独自{どくじ}の表現{ひょうげん}です。もちろん夏目漱石はこの文章を書{か}いておりません。「退屈嵩じて石になる」という文章に私が込｛こ｝めた意味｛いみ｝は次｛つぎ｝のとおりです。「ああ、退屈｛たいくつ｝だ。何｛なに｝をするのも面倒｛めんどう｝だ。少｛すこ｝しも動｛うご｝きたくない。そう思｛おも｝って動かないでじっとしていると、まるで石のようだ。そうだ。いっそのこと、人間｛にんげん｝をやめて石になったら、退屈なんてつまらないことも感｛かん｝じなくてよいし、楽｛らく｝になるだろう。」
5. 【訂正{ていせい}】
   上記{じょうき}の３．で説明{せつめい}した「ＡはＢになる」は日本語{にほんご}として自然{しぜん}ですが、Ａ、Ｂのいずれか一方{いっぽう}が物{もの}でない場合{ばあい}は不自然{ふしぜん}です。という部分{ぶぶん}は、次{つぎ}の例{れい}（２）が見{み}つかりましたので訂正{ていせい}します。
   （１）具象物{ぐしょうぶつ}が具象物{ぐしょうぶつ}になる例{れい}：「蛹{さなぎ}は蝶{ちょう}になる。」「その男{おとこ}は医者{いしゃ}になる。」
   （２）具象物{ぐしょうぶつ}が抽象概念{ちゅうしょうがいねん}になる例{れい}：「その医者{いしゃ}は幸福{こうふく}になる。」
   （３）抽象概念{ちゅうしょうがいねん}が具象物{ぐしょうぶつ}になる例{れい}：「退屈{たいくつ}は石{いし}になる」。

## English

1. As a conclusion, I don't dare to say that the sentence "Taikutsu wa ishi ni naru" is incomplete as a Japanese one, but I felt it unnatural. Therefore I don't think it has effective meaning to judge whether Mr. Publo understands the meaning of the original Japanese sentence correctly by means of judging the translated English sentence "boredom becomes a stone" by him.
2. When I searched on the Internet for this sentence "taikutsu wa ishi ni naru," I found the similar one in http://anond.hatelabo.jp/20170213160617. It may be expressed for the first time as a Japanese phrase or sentence. The expression on the Internet is like a poem constructed in three lines; "(woo-hoo) taikutsu wa ～" " (woo-hoo) ishi ni naru ～" "omoku te ― ochichau ― mae ni", and it seems to try to express boredom (ennui in French) by the whole arrangement of the lines.
3. Let's consider not the poem-like phrase in the Internet but the sentence "taikutsu wa ishi ni naru" given by the questioner. I think the sentence which has a structure "A becomes B." is grammatically correct as a Japanese sentence. For example, "A pupa becomes a butterfly. (Sanagi wa chou ni naru)" can be said as a grammatically correct Japanese sentence. The sentence "a pupa becomes a butterfly" is considered to be made by omitting the part "to molt" in the sentence "a pupa molts and becomes a butterfly (Sanagi wa uka shite chou ni naru.)" In this case, A and B are both physically concrete objects (including creatures.) But in the topical sentence "taikutsu wa ishi ni naru (Boredom becomes a stone)", although B (= stone) is a concrete object, A (= boredom) isn't concrete. When both of A and B are concrete objects, a sentence "A becomes B (= A wa B ni naru)" is natural as a Japanese sentence, but when one of A or B isn't a concrete object, the sentence is unnatural. But I think only when a literally talented person such as an excellent author/writer would like to show his/her feeling in an expression of sentences accurately and he/she uses a metaphorical way, even when one of A or B isn't a concrete object, the unnatural Japanese sentences may be allowed to exist.
4. When I saw this sentence by the questioner, firstly I imagined a scene where Soseki Natsume,  a great and famous Japanese writer, murmured "boredom grows on and becomes a stone (taikutsu kouji te ishi ni naru)" expressing his disconsolate lassitude of himself. "Boredom grows on and becomes a stone" is my original expression that I rewrote based on "a boredom becomes a stone". Of course Soseki Natsume did not write this sentence. The meanings that I put in the sentence are as follows; Oh, I am bored. Whatever I do is troublesome. I do not want to move at all. When I think and feel like that and keep still without moving, I feel I'm totally like a stone. Well, if I resign as a human being and become the stone, I need not feel that boredom is dull, and I will become rather comfortable instead.

Comment: You can post an English translation in the same post (here).

Comment: I like he added the hiragana reading to many kanjis. It must be very tedious to do, but helpful for those who are learning kanjis

Comment: It's from Dragon Ball Super opening song. https://www.letras.com/kiyoshi-hikawa/limit-break-x-survivor/